# Access Denied on wfpub

Tags: 2010, workflow

I tried to google it but can't find a concrete definition. I have an  "Access Denied" error on this list. The browser gives me this

`http://servername/_layouts/AccessDenied.aspx?Source=http%3A%2F%2Fservername%3A1002%2FPages%2FPage.aspx&Type=list&name={2CE1B06E-1246-4B03-B8EB-6B59C0012F5F}`

Where list GUID `2CE1B06E-1246-4B03-B8EB-6B59C0012F5F` is `wfpub`

I only have this error if I log in with read-only permission. Does it have to do with permission settings? Please help me on how to fix this issue.

Comment: What were you doing when you got the access denied? You tagged it workflow, but the only connection I see to workflow is the list name.

Comment: @Tom: I was logging into the site (I got the error after entering the password). The list that is associated with the workflow is in a content query web part on the home page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine the permissions for that document library, you can browse to _catalog\wfpub from the all files menu in SharePoint Designer. Right click on the document library and select Properties to get to a page with a link to the browser adminisrtation page.

Or you can put the GUID for the list in the parameters for the administration page like:
http://servername/_layouts/listedit.aspx?List={2CE1B06E-1246-4B03-B8EB-6B59C0012F5F}